# Arabic font rendering on the Web differ from Photoshop

Tags: css, web, fonts, arabic, arabic-support

I'm trying to create a simple quote generator, I have the photoshop file and the design and trying to duplicate it to run on the web.

I ran into a problem where an Arabic font ([Adobe Naskh](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/adobe-naskh)) renders in a strange way when using `letter-spacing`.

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOi0j.png)
[Letter spacing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SCQC.png)

And this is the image in Photoshop:
[Font in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16Qr.png)

I'm expecting the image to render just fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16Qr.png)

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to guess what causes the problem without seeing the code. But you can try `line-height: normal` in CSS.

Comment: This is impossible to achieve. Adobe has always refused to share its know-how on fonts, and fonts used outside of its own software (like those on the web) use different font rendering software.